# How to put this PHP in table form?

Tags: php, html, datatable

How can I put an HTML table in this code that will separate the information, like for example separate "name" from "jomark"?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $idnumber=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE idnumber='$idnumber'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo <tr>'Name:</tr> '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['middlename'].' '.$row['lastname'].'<br>';
        echo <tr>'Student No:</tr> '.$row['idnumber'].'<br>';
        echo 'Department: '.$row['department'].'<br>';
        echo 'Course: '.$row['course'].'<br>';
        echo 'Major: '.$row['major'].'<br>';
        echo 'Year Level: '.$row['yearlevel'].'<br>';
        echo 'Sex: '.$row['sex'].'<br>';
        echo 'Status: '.$row['status'].'<br>';
        echo 'Date of Birth: '.$row['dateofbirth'].'<br>';
        echo 'Place of Birth: '.$row['placeofbirth'].'<br>';
        echo 'Nationality: '.$row['nationality'].'<br>';
        echo 'Address: '.$row['address'].'<br>';
        echo 'Mobile Number: '.$row['mobilenum'].'<br>';
        echo 'Email Address: '.$row['emailaddress'].'<br>';
        echo 'Guardian: '.$row['guardian'].'<br>';
    }
    </table>
?>
```

Here is the current output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The details of the individual in the image - are they of a real student?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first I'll suggest you to use divs instead of using tables but here the solution.

```
<table>
<?php
    $idnumber=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE idnumber='$idnumber'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<tr><td>Name:</td><td>'.$row['firstname'].'</td><td>'.$row['middlename'].'</td><td>'.$row['lastname'].'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Student No:</td><td>'.$row['idnumber'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Department:</td><td>'.$row['department'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Course:</td><td>'.$row['course'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Major:</td><td>'.$row['major'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Year Level:</td><td>'.$row['yearlevel'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Sex:</td><td>'.$row['sex'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Status:</td><td>'.$row['status'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Date of Birth:</td><td>'.$row['dateofbirth'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Place of Birth:</td><td>'.$row['placeofbirth'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Nationality:</td><td>'.$row['nationality'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td>'.$row['address'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Mobile Number:</td><td>'.$row['mobilenum'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Email Address:</td><td>'.$row['emailaddress'].'</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Guardian:</td><td>'.$row['guardian'].' </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>';
    }
?>
</table>
```